# Redis pubsub и горизонтальное масшабирование?

Tags: node.js, redis

Для обмена данными между различными сервисами используется pubsub. При создании нескольких воркеров, они оба примут данные и оба их обработают. Какие есть методы, что бы на одно сообщение сработал только один из воркеров.

P.S Вероятно есть какие то прослойки, так называемые брокеры сообщений

Comment: Полагаю нужно смотреть в сторону Messaging Queue, например, https://www.rabbitmq.com/

Comment: Да, вероятно. Он умеет распределять сообщения между воркерами? Так сказать выступать как некий балансировщик?

Comment: Он может, конечно, выступать как балансировщик. В этом и состоит его задача, распределять задачи между сервисами в соотвествии с нагрузкой на каждый из них.

Comment: Да, спасибо за наводку, прочитал докуметацию, действительно может.